# How to add always +1 to 0 in python

Tags: selenium, numbers, addition

how to do if i start script to number of views one was always added? This function is on the end of script, and dosent work :(

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time
 webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= r'chromedriver.exe')
 
 Timer = 3 
 
 link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gz-kUmx1GmE'
 
 views = 10
 n = 0
 
 driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
 driver.get(link)
 
 for i in range(views):
     time.sleep(Timer)
     if driver.refresh():
         print("View ", n + (1))
     else:
         print("View ", n + (1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of understand that you're trying to add "+1" to n variable. If that's the case, it would be better if that part of your code would be like

```
if driver.refresh()
   n += 1
```

This is what I sort of get about what you're trying to do